# Encrypt - Decrypt AES PHP - URL one time use only

Tags: php, url, encryption

I managed to make a code to encrypt and decrypt data in AES-CCM in PHP language. This code retrieves data, sends it to a server and adds it to a database via post URL. But if someone has access to the URL and sends it several times to the server, it will add data to the database each time.
Is there a simple way to prohibit this URL after one adding data?

**Edit : I think I will add date and hour in the encryption part. Then when I will receive data, I will check date and hour with +-1min. And check if I have not already receive this message. 
What do you think about this solution?! Is that easy is to crack it?!**

This is my code (Fisrt part) :

```
$algo  = 'aes-128-ccm';
$iv    = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($algo));
$key   = "cd9344040aa9f9217871d46ee871c59c"; 
$data = '00000000010-3b57af';
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
    $data,
    $algo,
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $iv,
    $tag
);
$ciphertext = bin2hex($ciphertext);
$iv = bin2hex($iv);
$tag = bin2hex($tag);
echo'<a href="adddata1?data='.$ciphertext.'&tag='.$tag.'&iv='.$iv.'">"decrypte"</a>';
?>
```

The second part :

```
$algo  = 'aes-128-ccm';
$key   = "cd9344040aa9f9217871d46ee871c59c"; 

$ciphertext = hex2bin($_GET['data']);
$iv = hex2bin($_GET['iv']);
$tag = hex2bin($_GET['tag']);

$decrypt = openssl_decrypt(
    $ciphertext,
    $algo,
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $iv,
    $tag
);
if (false === $decrypt) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf(
        "OpenSSL error: %s", openssl_error_string()
    ));
}
```